# React updating state leads to change in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am updating my state with props first and then making changes in the state, but those changes are also changing the props, which is creating problem.

data getting from props

```
tableData = {
  id: 5,
  indexField: false,
  lockValue: false,
  values: [
    {
      listValue: 'PL-1',
      listDisplay: 'Tea' 
    },
    {
      listValue: 'PL-2',
      listDisplay: 'Coffee' 
    }
  ]
}
```

updated my state from props

```
tableDataState = {
  id: 5,
  indexField: false,
  lockValue: false,
  values: [
    {
      listValue: 'PL-1',
      listDisplay: 'Tea' 
    },
    {
      listValue: 'PL-2',
      listDisplay: 'Coffee' 
    }
  ]
}
```

Code updating the state

```
const listOptions = this.state.tableDataState.values;
let formattedValue = '';
  if (isArray(listOptions)) {
    listOptions.map((option) => {
      formattedValue = formattedValue + ` ${option.listDisplay}`;
      return option;
    });
  }
this.setState({ tableDataState: [...listOptions] });
```

expecting `this.state.tableDataState` as below and getting as expected.

```
tableDataState = {
  id: 5,
  indexField: false,
  lockValue: false,
  values: 'Tea Coffee'
}
```

But the props from where the data is derived, `this.props.tableData` is also getting changed as `this.state.tableDataState`.

Please help me resolving this.

Comment: Hello. It is a bit unclear as to what you are trying to do. I think you must provide clear code. Most probably its the same object reference which you are mutating and hence even props.tableData has the same change. Also, the code which you mentioned as updating the state has something odd there. you use map on listOptions but you enver use the result of that map call. Not sure entirey what you are doing to be able to answer.

Comment: A JSON structure is not "code".  We'll need the code you're actually using, particularly where you're setting props, which isn't there.  Also, several of your "code sections" are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assigned object directly here.

```
const listOptions = this.state.tableDataState.values;
```

Because of this, changes in the state results in changes in the props. The solution is to clone object in an exact way.
You can check this link.
https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/

I prefer using Lodash deep clone. You can also use JSON in your case, I think.